# Change value of a row and add a total row in SQL

Tags: sql

For performance reasons, I have to adapt some of my SQL queries.
Here's my query and its result :

```
SELECT 
    CODACT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup = 10 THEN CUMCOL END) AS aprep, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup = 20 THEN CUMCOL END) AS encours, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup > 20 THEN CUMCOL END) AS prepares, 
    SUM(CUMCOL) AS total 
FROM 
    FGE50NEUV1.GESUPE 
WHERE 
    TYPSUP = '1' 
    AND (DATLIV >= ` + date(0) +` 
         AND DATLIV <= ` + date(addDays) + `) 
GROUP BY 
    CODACT
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    CODACT: 'AUA',
    APREP: 6503,
    ENCOURS: 244,
    PREPARES: 30180,
    TOTAL: 36927
  },
  {
    CODACT: 'AUF',
    APREP: null,
    ENCOURS: null,
    PREPARES: 73,
    TOTAL: 73
  },
  {
    CODACT: 'LID',
    APREP: 12597,
    ENCOURS: 128,
    PREPARES: 21556,
    TOTAL: 34281
  },
  {
    CODACT: 'MAT',
    APREP: 410,
    ENCOURS: null,
    PREPARES: 5059,
    TOTAL: 5469
  }
]
```

I would like to merge the two rows "AUA" and "AUF" and change the merged row name to "Auchan", and then add a row with CODACT "TOTAL" which contains all the SUM of previous values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is easy - replace `CODACT` with `case when CODACT in ('AUA', 'AUF') then 'Auchan' else CODACT end`, both in `SELECT` (you need to add alias  `as CODACT` there) and `GROUP BY` parts.

Second part (add row with total) is most easily solved by CTE:

```
with CTE as (SELECT 
    CODACT, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup = 10 THEN CUMCOL END) AS aprep, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup = 20 THEN CUMCOL END) AS encours, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN etasup > 20 THEN CUMCOL END) AS prepares, 
    SUM(CUMCOL) AS total 
FROM 
    FGE50NEUV1.GESUPE 
WHERE 
    TYPSUP = '1' 
    AND (DATLIV >= ` + date(0) +` 
         AND DATLIV <= ` + date(addDays) + `) 
GROUP BY 
    CODACT
)
select CODACT, aprep, encours, prepares, total
from CTE
union all
select 'TOTAL', sum(aprep), sum(encours), sum(prepares), sum(total)
from CTE
```

You can combine both these improvements.
I didn't check syntax, sorry :)

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your response you save me a lot of hours lol. It's almost perfect, just for the AUA and AUF rows I don't juste have to change the name but also merge them by adding the APREP, ENCOURS and TOTAL values

Comment: This `case when CODACT in ('AUA', 'AUF') then 'Auchan' else CODACT end` merges them; if you need both original and merged rows, then you have to play with merging in additional union part. You may accept my answer also, unless someone posts another, better working one.

Comment: I just did and it doesn't merge them, just change their name

Comment: Did you replace `group by` expression also?

Comment: What do you mean by "GROUP BY parts" ?

Comment: `group by case when CODACT in ('AUA', 'AUF') then 'Auchan' else CODACT end` - sorry english is not my first or second language :(

Comment: OMG it works thanks a lot ! The only thing that didn't work is for the total row

Comment: Did you get some error?

Comment: Maybe I did a mistake, I retried today and it works perfectly, thanks a lot for all @Arvo !